# MVC3 unhandeld exceptiion logging without elmah

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, unhandled-exception

Elmah is nice but its a bit heavyduty for this little business app and we already have a log and view for the backend exceptions.

OK so I have enabled customs errors and use the MVC3 HandleErrorAttribute to render a custom page, this works nice. But as far as I understand there is no way of connecting a Controller to it, so its really no way of injecting a logger and log. I could use the Appplicationerror method in global asax, but you cant inject your logger into the globalasax in a good way.

So whats the best way of catching an unhandleded exception inject the logger using your favorite IoC and log it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this, inherit from HandleErrorAttribute which has my logger interface as constructor argument.

then bind that filter to my IoC, in my case Ninject

```
kernel.BindFilter<HandleAndLogErrorAttribute >(FilterScope.Global, 0);
```